# Unsure what to make of the following Emacs prompt to change my init file

Tags: init-file, package, debugging

Every time I open emacs, I get the following error; emacs is working fine, but not giving me the initial help screen:

```
An error has occurred while loading `/Users/thorkamphefner/.emacs.d/init.el':

File error: Cannot open load file, package

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

When I enter debug mode, I get the following prompt, which I'm not sure how to read. Line 44 in my init file looks like it has nothing to do with the error described.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "package")
  require(package)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/thorkamphefner/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 44
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/thorkamphefner/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/thorkamphefner/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/thorkamphefner/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[nil "^H\205\276^@   \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202A^@ \311=\2033^@\312\307\313\314#\203#^@\315\202A^@\312\307\313\3$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Reading at buffer position 44 doesn't mean line. To go to the position with the problem, open your init.el and use M-x goto-char 44.

Comment: What version of Emacs do you have? It seems strange that it can't find `package` which has been built-in since Emacs 24.

Comment: M-x goto-char 44 <ret> puts me at the end of (require 'package), which is followed by some add-to-lists.

Comment: I have version 26.2

Comment: That is exactly the problem pointed out by npostavs. For some reason your emacs can't find package. Two possibilities, package is missing or in a path, that is not found by your emacs. I am sorry, I have no idea why package is not found.

Comment: Okay, think I'll just reinstall :P

Comment: What you could do to try to understand what's going on is: `C-h v load-path`. This will open help buffer listing all locations where Emacs looks for its ELisp sources. This may be a long list, depending on your config. Not sure what the default location on Mac would be, but look in this list for something like `emacs/26.2/lisp` or `emacs/26.2/site-lisp` etc. This is where your missing package *should* be.

Comment: I discovered that it appears the melpa seems to be causing the problem. When I toyed with commenting these lines: 
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
The error window disappears. I don't understand why, and when I use M-x package-list-packages, the list appears fine.

Comment: My crystal ball suggests maybe you have installed Emacs-26.2 but you're instead unwittingly running Apple's crappy Emacs-22.